# Python/Pandas - Checking the list of values in pandas column for a condition

Tags: python, pandas

I have a python program which process multiple files. Each file have customer id column based on value in city column. Some file has 8 digit customer id and some have 9 digit customer id. I need to do this -

```
if column city value is in ['Chicago', 'Newyork', 'Milwaukee', 'Dallas']:
    input_file['customer_id'] = input_file['customer_id'].str[0:2] + '-' + input_file['customer_id'].str[2:8]
Else:
    input_file['customer_id'] = 'K' + '-' + input_file['customer_id'].str[0:3] + '-' + input_file['customer_id'].str[3:8]
```

Input

```
id cusotmerid  city
1  89898988    Dallas
2  898989889   Houston
```

Output

```
id cusotmerid     city
1  89-898988      Dallas
2  K-898-989889   Houston
```

How can I achieve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check with `np.where`

```
l =  ['Chicago', 'Newyork', 'Milwaukee', 'Dallas']
s1 = df['customer_id'].str[0:2] + '-' + df['customer_id'].str[2:8]
s2 = 'K' + '-' + df['customer_id'].str[0:3] + '-' + df['customer_id'].str[3:8]
df['cusotmerid'] = np.where(df['city'].isin(l), s1, s2)
```